# I want to add a progress bar to my lambda function

Tags: python, progress-bar, pysimplegui

## What we want to do

I would like to add a progress bar because it is difficult to see the progress during translation.

Currently, we are using PysimpleGUI for other settings, but it is something that will be displayed after various settings are completed.
The library to be used does not have to be PysimpleGUI since the purpose is only to display a progress bar.

## Method Description

Tran : Translation.
exclude : formatting.

## Code

```
# Format the description, translate it and put it in df['title'].
df['title'] = df['description'].apply(lambda i: Tran(exclude(i)))
```

#### Tran method

```
def Tran(text):
    # Start browser in headless mode
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')

    # Start the browser
    DRIVER_PATH = ". /chromedriver" # Path to your chromedriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get(url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(30) # wait up to 30 seconds if not found

    sleep_time = 10
    try_max_count = 30
    for i in range(try_max_count):
        # Wait for specified time
        time.sleep(sleep_time)  
        html = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='lxml')
        target_elem = soup.find(class_="lmt__translations_as_text__text_btn")
        translated_text = target_elem.text
        # Confirmation that DeepL has been translated
        if translated_text:
            return(translated_text)
            break

    # Stop browser
    driver.quit()
```

#### exclude method

```
def exclude(s):
    s = re.sub(r "http\S+", "", s)
    s = re.sub(r"@(\w+) ", "", s)
    s = re.sub(r "#(\w+)", "", s)
    s = re.sub(r"(^RT.*)", "", s, flags=re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL) # any (multi-line) string starting with RT

    emoji_pattern = re.compile("["
    u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"
    u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"
    u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"
    u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF}"
    "]+", flags=re.UNICODE)
    s = emoji_pattern.sub("", s)

    return s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I use `Text` element to show the progress, and multi-threading for your translation because it may take long time to have GUI no responding.

Demo Code

```py
from time import sleep
import threading
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def job(window, text):
    global stop
    total = 20
    for i in range(total):
        if stop:
            break
        sleep(0.2)      # step in your job
        window.write_event_value('Progress', (i+1, total))
    if not stop:
        window.write_event_value('Progress Done', 'Translated')

font = ('Courier New', 11)
sg.theme('BrownBlue')
sg.set_options(font=font, input_elements_background_color='green',
    input_text_color='white')

size = 80
layout = [
    [sg.Multiline('', size=(10, 10), expand_x=True, key='INPUT' ),
     sg.Multiline('', size=(10, 10), expand_x=True, key='Result')],
    [sg.Button('Send', expand_x=True)],
    [sg.Text('', size=size, relief='sunken', text_color='yellow', key='BAR')],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
stop = False
while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        stop = True
        sleep(0.5)
        break

    elif event == 'Send':           # Start your job
        text = values['INPUT']
        window['BAR'].update('')
        window['Result'].update('')
        if text == '':
            continue
        window['Send'].update(disabled=True)
        threading.Thread(target=job, args=(window, text), daemon=True).start()

    elif event == 'Progress':       # Each step in your job
        steps, total = values[event]
        state = int(steps/total*size)
        window['BAR'].update('█'*state)

    elif event == 'Progress Done':  # End of your job
        result = values[event]
        if result:
            window['Result'].update(result)
        window['Send'].update(disabled=False)

window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks,I hope used this place .```df['title'] = df['description'].apply(lambda i: Tran(exclude(i)))```  what would you do

Comment: I have no idea about pandas, just provide code to show you how to work about progressbar in PySimpleGUI. You can place code into function `job` and remember to call `window.write_event_value` to generate event to GUI in main thread.

Comment: thank you so much for this. stumbled across this while trying to prevent the GUI from locking up while a process is still running (eg. a progress bar updating slowly). your implementation of multi-threading showed me the way!

Answer (score 0):

There is a thing in PySimpleGUI call `ProgressBar`, you can add to it like normal object ([docs here](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/call%20reference/#progressbar-element)). But this might be hard to use, so you can use `OneLinePrrogressMeter` ([docs here](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/call%20reference/#one-line-progress-meter))

Example:

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Button('Test', key='test')]
]

window = sg.Window('example', layout=layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == 'test':
        for x in range(1000):
            sg.one_line_progress_meter(
                'example',
                x + 1,
                1000
            )
```