# Running multiple scripts simultaneously using PySimpleGui

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I built a Gui using Pysimplegui and the gui calls a method from a different script that runs an engine. The engine cycle takes 60 seconds and while it is running the gui freezes. i want to add a function that allows me to terminate the motor cycle from within the Gui.
Any suggestions?

```
    elif event == "RUN":
    try:
        run_from_xls(values['-TOUT-'], values['-COM-'])
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Use multi-threading, you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71462408/i-want-to-add-a-progress-bar-to-my-lambda-function/71486206#71486206

Comment: Great! This is actually very helpful. Thanks!